# Widget on backroud of widget

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

Is it posible in awesome wm to draw widget upper the other widget? As example: draw texbox with some text(percentages) on progressbar.

Here is worked solution

```
local function make_stack(w1, w2)
    local ret = wibox.widget.base.make_widget()

    ret.fit = function(self, ...) return w1:fit(...) end
    ret.draw = function(self, wibox, cr, width, height)
        w1:draw(wibox, cr, width, height)
        w2:draw(wibox, cr, width, height)
    end

    update = function() ret:emit_signal("widget::updated") end
    w1:connect_signal("widget::updated", update)
    w2:connect_signal("widget::updated", update)

    return ret
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like this built-in, but you can write it yourself (untested):

```
function make_stack(w1, w2)
  local ret = wibox.widget.base.make_widget()

  local update = function() ret:emit_signal("widget::updated") end
  w1:connect_signal("widget::updated", update)
  w2:connect_signal("widget::updated", update)

  ret.fit = function(self, ...) return w2:fit(...) end
  ret.draw = function(self, wibox, cr, width, height)
    wibox.layout.base.draw_widget(wibox, cr, w1, 0, 0, width, height)
    wibox.layout.base.draw_widget(wibox, cr, w2, 0, 0, width, height)
  end

  return ret
end
```

The function `make_stack(w1, w2)` creates a new widget that draws `w2` ontop of `w1`. The widget `w2` decides about the size that both widgets get, as can be seen in the `fit` function.

This can be used, for example, like this: `left_layout:add(make_stack(mytasklist[s], mytextclock))`